# Facebook Graph API Group Feed shows no posts past v2.3

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When accessing https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, I can use the URL `graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{groupID}/feed` and receive a list of posts from that group. Note that I am not the group administrator. See here:
[image: V2.3 Sorry for blacking out the image]

However, as soon as I change that to 2.4 or above, I can no longer receive any results:
[image: V2.4]

Even stranger, though, is the response time. V2.3 responded with actual content in 983MS, but V2.4 responded with nothing in 10,174MS. The long response time for nothing is indicative of every version, up to 2.9 (most recent version).

This is a real issue, because v2.3 is being deprecated July 10th, 2017. Any idea what's going on here? It doesn't appear that they've deprecated /{groupID}/feed, so why did it stop working for me?

Comment: Is it a public group?

Comment: @CBroe It's a closed group, but I'm a member (and so the Access Token generated for my user should work)

Comment: Normal users can not read the feed of closed groups any more.

Comment: @CBroe Well, that's very annoying. And a little weird, because I can see the posts just fine via the UI, which means I have to write a scraper instead of something that uses the API. Anyway, thanks for the information - if you'd like to add that as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal users can not read the feed of closed groups any more.

And no, you should not try and circumvent that by building a scraper, because scraping is not allowed. Users *have* the ability to view the group posts via the FB UI, and that should be all that is needed.

> Well, that's very annoying. And a little weird, because I can see the posts just fine via the UI

Yes, *you* can. But with an app, an additional party comes into play: The developer of that app, who could be the shadiest person sitting in wherever, doing whatever with the user data their app can read. And now imagine you were member of a closed group, where people might discuss sensitive issues such as health, sexual abuse, etc. Would you really want every other group member to be able to give an app you know nothing about access to what you posted in such a group …? No, of course not. And therefor that decision has been placed in the hands of the group admin(s) now.

Comment: You're definitely correct, but from another point of view - my user was, and still is, able to view the groups' information. I was generating an access token for myself to use, effectively just making an API user for myself. You're correct that I don't want *other* apps viewing information from groups that I'm in, so...I just wouldn't give the apps permission for that, or to post things on my wall, etc. But I guess not everyone is vigilant about privacy.

Comment: Also, another slightly weird thing - it takes 10x as long to return me nothing with the new API versions, when really it should just respond saying "The API cannot view closed groups for non-admins" immediately or something like that. Would have saved me a step!

Comment: That you want to use an app just for yourself is the exception from the norm; but the usual case is that it is a 3rd party, that users just grant permissions to. And _“I just wouldn't give the apps permission for that”_ won’t help you protect your privacy, if _someone else_ where to use such an app and gave it permission to read the group feed.

Comment: But I agree that it is somewhat inconsistent to return an empty data structure here, instead of an error message; there’s enough other endpoints that would just do the latter, if the requesting user does not have sufficient permission. I don’t know if there’s technical reasons behind that here.

Comment: I'm definitely the exception, but it seems like a bit of group punishment - "we can't trust the users to divvy up permissions properly, so we'll remove the ability to read from groups entirely" (unless you're an admin). It's not such a huge deal, I was just archiving a group over time, but I guess I can't anymore

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately now v2.12 doesn't give any group feed unless you have the access token for the admin of the group (public-closed-secret).